# unable to redirect to html page in flask

Tags: html, flask, logout

I'm returning the specific message through an endpoint in flask .

```
  return '''  <h1>  User does not exist </h1>      <a href  = "{{url_for('logout')}}"> Logout </a> '''
```

I get redirected to the page but when I press the logout link I get that URL does not exist . 
This is my logout endpoint . It works perfectly in any different case .

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # remove the email from the session if it's there
    session.pop('Email', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I would appreciate your guidance in helping me solve this issue . Thank you in advance .

Comment: I would suggest you to return the flask template using `render_template` method rather than returning the html content as string.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I could but isn't this more simple ? Instead of making more and more html pages ?

Comment: Could you look at the URL, after you click at logout and show?

Comment: @ngShravil.py No I get http://127.0.0.1:5000/%7B%7Burl_for_logout%7D%7D . Hope this helps more